# No availavility in Advanced Shopping (SABRE)

Tags: sabre

¿Hi, someone knows why [this](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/sabre_sonic_apis/soap/select_shop/advanced_shopping) service responds with "No Availability"?

I have tried with various routes without success :(

Request:

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ PrimaryLangID="ENG"  xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"  Version="1.9.7">
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="9V">
            <RequestorID ID="String" Type="0.AAA.X" URL="">
                <CompanyName Code="9V" CodeContext="Context"/>
            </RequestorID>
        </Source>
    </POS>
    <OriginDestinationInformation >
        <DepartureDateTime>2017-10-15T15:55:0</DepartureDateTime>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="AUA"/>
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="VLN"/>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <TravelerInfoSummary>
            <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
            <AirTravelerAvail>
                <PassengerTypeQuantity Age="40" Quantity="1"/>
            </AirTravelerAvail>
        </TravelerInfoSummary>
    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

response:

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS Version="1.9.7" PricedItinCount="0" BrandedOneWayItinCount="0" SimpleOneWayItinCount="0" DepartedItinCount="0" SoldOutItinCount="0" AvailableItinCount="0" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Errors>
        <Error Type="MAIN" Code="DEPRECATEDRS" ShortText="This response version is deprecated and will be decommissioned once two newer versions are released."/>
        <Error Type="WORKERTHREAD" Code="TRANSACTIONID" MessageClass="I" ShortText="8004820706222027676"/>
        <Error Type="SERVER" Code="TTFHLC700" MessageClass="I" ShortText="27038"/>
        <Error Type="SERVER" Code="MSG" MessageClass="I">No Availability</Error>
        <Error Type="ERR" Code="NAV" ShortText="No Availability"/>
     </Errors>
  </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS>
```

thanks, i wil keep trying!

Answer (score 1):

There can be various reasons behind that. In any case the message implies that there are literally no availabilities (0) in any booking classes. However, schedules are available. so, either the flights have not been opened yet or are booked out. You might also be working on the wrong Sabre partition, etc.

Also, I am not sure how you set this up with Sabre but 9V does not look like a usual PCC to me (generally 3 letter city codes)