# No availavility in Advanced Shopping SabreSonic Soap Api

Tags: .net, soap, sabre

am getting this response whith the Advanced Shopping api, its my first time consuming SabreSonic apis and i need some help. The request parameters are fine.

Is there any difference between SabreSonic Soap apis and sabre soap apis?

Thanks!!!

No Availability

Comment: Need more details. Please explain the context and exactly what response you're getting. It is also useful to list down the steps you have taken to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596740/no-availavility-in-advanced-shopping-sabre this same results, sorry i couldnt post an image of may code.

Comment: The thing is, i've been using this sabre apis, using web References on a .NET proyect, i start getting a session with SessionCreateRQ and it works fine! i tried with anothers api (sabre soap apis) and it works fine too, but with SabreSonic apis got this problem. PD: sorry if my english its not so good

Comment: What is the environment are you using ? what is the services orchestration are you using and finally what is your payload request ? The link with the "same  result" you shared is not a valid example, the PCC is invalid, it does not have the environment endpoint and lots of informations to debugg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, the problem was a missing tag
    `<TPA_Extensions>
         <IntelliSellTransaction>
             <ServiceTag Name="XXX"/>
         </IntelliSellTransaction>
    </TPA_Extensions>`

XXX = Carrier code

Answer (score 0):

Sabre Sonic is designed for Airline Partners - i guess you are a travel network developer therefore you should use the "normal" sabre soap apis